# How do I access my post data in a asp.net mvc editor view?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have gotten this semi autogenerated code, but I am uncertain where the Post data is saved and how I access the variables in my controller so I can validate and upload it to my database.

```
    @model FirstWeb.Models.Picture

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload et billede";

}

<h2>Upload et billede</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>



@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConcertYear)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConcertYear)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConcertYear)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Tilbage til billeder", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to upload files here. Checkout the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx). You will need to use a `multipart/form-data` enctype for your form in order to be able to upload files. So the first step is to fix your form definition:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
    ...
}
```

then update your view model so that it takes the uploaded file as property:

```
public class Picture
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ConcertYear { get; set; }

    ... some other properties used in the view
}
```

and and finally have your controller POST action take this view model as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(Picture model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // there were validation errors => re-display the view
        return View(model);
    }

    // the model is valid at this stage => check if the user uploaded a file
    if (model.File != null && model.File.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // the user uploaded a file => process it ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes thats the point, but first I need to be able to access my Post data in my controller which is what I am strugling with atm.

Comment: @Mech0zm your POST controller action would take the view model as parameter. This view model will contain all the form values.

Comment: So I need a 2 public ActionResult Upload() one that returns the view and one that takes Picture as parameter and have the [HttpPost] attribute to handle the items I get?

Comment: @Mech0z, precisely, you need two actions: one for serving the form and accessible through GET and one for handling he form submission accessible through POST.

Comment: How is it I get the fileinformation saved in my public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; } everytime I try to test it the model.File is null using this http://pastebin.com/h2fqPp41

Comment: @Mech0z, you have nested 2 forms and this is not valid. You should have only one `Html.BeginForm` and it is this form that should have the `enctype` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The Edit action should take your model as a parameter.

Its proeprties will have the edited values.

Comment: How do I access that model parameter? (I am new to asp.net) If I write @Model.ConcertYear in my view it complains and there is no Model variable accessable in my Controller

Comment: You need to add a parameter to the function.